# Laravel - return array of relationships in laravel model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to return a array in my services relationship.
In my output, I want something like:

```
services: {
 true: {...},
 false: {...},
}
```

The relationship it self is working. If I just

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')->wherePivot('includes_it', 1)
```

Then it works fine. But I want to go deeper. I want that the services method returns an array with a false, and a true key.

Like here:

```
public function services()
    {
        return [
            "true" => $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')->wherePivot('includes_it', 1),
            "false" => $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')->wherePivot('includes_it', 0)
        ];
    }
```

But what I get is:

Error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the relationship feature of laravel in a wrong way in your second approach.

What you could do, for example, is to define two relationship functions on your model like this:

```
public function servicesIncluded()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')
        ->wherePivot('includes_it', 1);
}

public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')
        ->wherePivot('includes_it', 0);
}
```

Then you could do something like this (assuming you model is called Product):

```
$products_included = Product::servicesIncluded()->get();
$prodcuts_excluded = Product::services()->get();
$result = [
    "true" => $products_included,
    "false" => $products_excluded
];
```

Or you could include the pivot column in your relationship like this:

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'product_services', 'product_id', 'service_id')
        ->withPivot('includes_it');
}
```

Comment: My problem is, that I need it like:

services : {
 true: ...
 false: ...
}

Comment: see updated answer. If I understand you correctly that should give you your result.